# Why system takes up so much space on Mac?

Tags: mac

How can I reduce system space? I removed from trash everything, what else I can do?

Reinstall again computer?

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: Time Machine snapshots?

Comment: Did you see this question? [“System” storage on macOS Sierra is 470GB!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261252/system-storage-on-macos-sierra-is-470gb)