# How to free up storage space associated with "System" on macbook pro mojave OS?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

The laptop apparently is taking up ~87 gigabytes of space for system. I don't know how to dig into the details of why and to look into possibly freeing up some of that space as that seems rather excessive. I asked a friend and they only had ~11gb associated with system.[image]

I did have a hard time upgrading from high sierra to mojave, and had to do a reboot into safe mode then hit some buttons on the app store to install mojave which eventually seemed to work.

Comment: I'm not sure we have a true canonical answer to this, but see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261252/system-storage-on-macos-sierra-is-470gb and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space It is a common concern.

Comment: I can vouch for DaisyDisk and OmniDiskSweeper to see where all this System space went, but the decision on what to delete it will be ultimately yours.